# Adding alternative media source folders to Rygel

Tags: streaming, xbmc, dlna, upnp, rygel

I recently setup Rygel on my laptop to play my media collection from a Raspberry Pi running XBMC. It works well so far, however, I cannot seem to find a way to add any other folder to the index apart from the default home folders for Music, Pictures and Videos. 
The problem is, most of my media are is a separate partition on my laptop, and I cannot move them over to the home partition because there isn't enough space, So, I'm wondering if there is a way to add other media sources folders to Rygel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either install **Rygel preferences from the ubuntu software center** which is a gui to edit Rygel's directories or edit the file using you favorite text editor 
*the file's location is:*

```
  /home/(your user name)/.config/rygel.conf
```

and edit/add/delete items in the line

```
uris=@MUSIC@;/home/rt/Videos/1 tv;
```

If your folders don't show up you may want too edit the file:

**/home/(your user name)/.config/rygel.conf** 
set [Tracker] to false and [MediaExport] to true.  See example below

This also fixes a problem with the folder "**Files & Folders**" not showing up as a choice

```
[Tracker]
enabled=false


[MediaExport]
enabled=true
```